# How to write a callback for the asynchronous function below

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, swift3, callback

I have a function I'm using below. I want the data from that asynchronous function but it comes up nil if I try to use the data outside the `fullResolutionImageData` function. So I have to write a callback. But I don't know how to write the callback. Can someone show me how to write a callback for the asynchronous function below so I can access the data elsewhere. Can you show me how to write a callback so I can access files outside `fullResolutionImageData` asynchronous function.

```
public func fullResolutionImageData(completion: @escaping (Data?) -> ()) {
    SharedQueues.imageProcessingQueue.addOperation { [path] in
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(data)
        }
    }
}
```

In my view controller I have an action that uses this function

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!){
        var photos2: [ImageSource]?
        var files : [Data] = []
        let _ = self.photos2?.map ({completion: path in
            path.fullResolutionImageData{ data in
                files.append(data) --> (prints 2)
            }
        })
        print("(files.count)") --> (prints 0 How do I write callback?)
    }
}
```

Comment: Implement your webservice in this structure manner : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46081822/3400991 follow this link instruction

Comment: I suggest using protocol/delegate pattern to notify your `ViewController` once the image processing is completed.

Comment: could you make an edit and show me how to do this. I'm a little confused. I'm new to coding and haven't learned much protocols

Comment: @toddg Could you show me what your talking about

Comment: Couldn't you just call an additional function within your completion block that is passed to `fullResolutionImageData`? You may not even need protocol/delegate. Here's more info: https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2016/02/15/fundamentals-of-callbacks-for-swift-developers/

Comment: @toddg Are you suggesting I create a function which captures the data from the completion handler so I can use it elsewhere.

Comment: I'm suggesting you create a function that is called within your completion block that is passed to `fullResolutionImageData`: `path.fullResolutionImageData{ data in
                files.append(data) --> (prints 2)
            doSomethingWith(filesCount: Int)}`

Comment: @toddg I looked at the website and I'm still a little confused about you idea. Can you make an edit and show me directly or add a note alongside my code to show me what your talking about. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: @toddg What will the function do

Comment: @Useruuu you should take your time to study asynchronous programming in detail. Your question clearly shows that you lack the basics of the problem and hence require answerers to show how to do something that just isn't possible. You want to access results of asynchronous functions just like they were synchronous ones, but that's not how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All u need is Dispatch Group.

```
func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!){
        var photos2: [ImageSource]?
        var files : [Data] = []

        let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
        let _ = self.photos2?.map ({completion: path in
            myGroup.enter()
            path.fullResolutionImageData{ data in
                files.append(data) --> (prints 2)
                myGroup.leave()
            }
        })

        myGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) { // 2
            print("(files.count)")
        }
    }
```

**Little bit of Explanation :**

Dispatch groups are used for monitoring the completion of multiple asynchronous tasks. Like in your case getting the data from the file path which u are performing on background thread.

**Things to be aware of :**

Every single tasks that enters the group should leave the group no matter whether it succeeds in its goal or not. If any of the task entered the group fail to exit the thread will be blocked forever. So make sure `fullResolutionImageData` always executes the completion block!

**EDIT:**

Finally As pointed out by [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4667835/d%C3%A1vid-p%C3%A1sztor/%22David%22) in comments it makes sense to use foreach loop then using map if u are discarding the results

hence use

```
func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!){
        var photos2: [ImageSource]?
        var files : [Data] = []

        let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
        photos2?.forEach{ path in
             myGroup.enter()
             path.fullResolutionImageData{ data in
                 files.append(data) --> (prints 2)
                 myGroup.leave()
             }
        }

        myGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) { // 2

        }
    }
```

Comment: So where can I access the file count outside the function. Is it in dispatch.notify

Comment: I know you just copied that part from OP, but don't use `map` if you are discarding the return value. Use `forEach` if you want to keep the syntax.

Comment: @useruuu : Yes sir!!! Please read the answer carefully. DispatchGroup is an amazing tool only as long as u know how to use it :D

Comment: @dávid-pásztor : Agreed 100%

Comment: @dávid-pásztor : Updated answer with ur suggestion and mentioned u in answer as well :) Thanks for the pointer :)

Comment: So one last thing why am I removed bing dispatch.main.async from full resolution image. Is it because it will block the thread

Comment: @useruuu : I din get ur question buddy

Comment: @SandeepBhandari that's actually not a `forEach`, that's a `for ... in` loop. The syntax for `forEach` is `yourArray.forEach{ element in ... }`, that's why I advised using it, it has the same trailing closure syntax as `map`.

Comment: Why did you remove dispatch.main.async from public func fullResolutionImageData(completion: @escaping (Data?) -> ()) {
    SharedQueues.imageProcessingQueue.addOperation { [path] in
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        completion(data)
    }
}

Comment: @useruuu : I am not really sure how dispatch_group is implemented internally. If my understanding is correct, it expects each thread which enters the block to leave the block. If u use main thread to execute the completion block in the above mentioned method then u'll execute myGroup.leave() in main thread though the thread that entered the group was not main thread. Am not really sure whether its thread dependent or not or if its simply implemented as a counter whenever counter becomes 0 it notifies the group as I am not sure and din wanted u to suffer with threads I asked u not to write it

Comment: I got the full resolution image from this repository https://github.com/avito-tech/Paparazzo. If you need money more information on the fullresolution function to determine if the main.dispatch is needed or not.

Comment: @useruuu : Ill check out when am free thanks buddy :) But the issue I mentioned is not related to any specific method/function. If ur code is working without dispatch.main.async try adding it and check if it works or not :) If it doesn't then my prediction is correct else I might be wrong in my assumption :) Give a try I believe if u add dispatch.main.async it will not work :D

Comment: Ok will give it a go tonight. Can you check in tomorrow to see my comment for an update

Comment: Thanks for helping me. You and David where the only ones who gave me an answer I could understand. I contacted the owner of the repository to ask him about this question and he was rude and told me to go to stackoverflow. I know fullresoultionimage function affected other functions in the repository that's why I asked you to look at it. I just searched fullresoulutionimage in the repository and 6 results came up. That's why I'm so hesitant to remove dispatch.main from it because I don't want to affect other functions in the project. Thanks.

Comment: @useruuu : Just wrote a code to find will code work with dispatch.async.main it won't so if the third party requires u to switch to main thread then ull need a little modified solution

Comment: What do you suggest that solution to be. Should I just delete dispatch.main or does it affect everything else

Comment: Because you say it wo t work should I just stick with your solution or will it create more problems down the line.

Comment: @useruuu : Am trying to find a way while not removing the Dipatch.main.async if I can find one Ill let u know till then remove the Dispatch.main.async and test if it works fine or not

Comment: Will do that. Could you let me know today what you think please.

Comment: Also your really helpful. Once we resolve this issue I was wondering if I could pay you to help me change my server from heroku to aws. And another thing I'd like you to help me with is private messaging. Is that something you'd be interested in for money.

Comment: @useruuu : Please see the updated answer. U don't have to change anything in any other method I confused u n myself with blocking main thread n all nothing of that sort happens so go ahead use it without commenting anything in third party library :) cheers and sorry I am little busy with my work as I am part of start up I won't be able to help u with servers and other stuff :) thanks for the offer though :)

Comment: Do you know anyone who's trustworthy